ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'u'
I just cannot multiply these 2 values together. It can't convert to an integer no matter what.
tbl_breed = ["Red Chittagong", "Sussex", "Dexter", "Abondance",
             "Sahiwal", "Vorderwald", "Ayrshire", "Jersey",
             "Randall", "Alderney", "Carora", "Gloucester"]
tbl_rating = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
tbl_count = [6, 3, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7]
tbl_volume = [7.5, 5.7, 11.4, 11.4,
              22.0, 15.2, 21.0, 18.3,
              19.0, 9.0, 23.1, 16.0]
tbl_dailyVolume = []
dailyvol = 0


x = 0
while x <12:
    totallist = [tbl_breed[x], tbl_rating[x], tbl_count[x], tbl_volume[x]]
    x = x + 1

    print(totallist)

for total in totallist:
    namebreed = total[0]
    rating = total[1]
    numcows = total[2]
    volmilk = total[3]

    volmik = int(float(volmilk))
    
    dailyvol = (numcows * volmilk)
    print(namebreed, ":", dailyvol)

The error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/squatpapa/Desktop/june2023 mock comp sci/Q06.py", line 30, in <module>
    volmik = int(float(volmilk))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'u'

I just wanted to multiply values to find the total, and the print them out in a loop next to the previous value in each list and output.

The code doesn't do what you think it does. It needs a re-think. Your while loop just keeps redefining totallist over and over, discarding the previous result. That's before you get to the error you're asking about

there's a mix-up with variable names. In your loop, you're attempting to convert volmilk to a float, but it appears volmilk is already a float. The error suggests that one of the values in volmilk is a string 'u'. Make sure all values in tbl_volume are valid numbers. Also, you're multiplying numcows by volmilk, but you probably meant to multiply by volmik, the converted value.

When you run your code, total is actually "Gloucester", so total[3] is, unsurprisingly "u". You meant to make a list of lists with a list comprehension.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here. Check out [ask]. For debugging help, we require a [mre], but in the process of making one, you can often find the problem yourself :) For help isolating the problem, see How to step through Python code to help debug issues?

You are redefining totallist again and again.
If you just want to multiply the values and display, you can try this.
tbl_breed = ["Red Chittagong", "Sussex", "Dexter", "Abondance",
             "Sahiwal", "Vorderwald", "Ayrshire", "Jersey",
             "Randall", "Alderney", "Carora", "Gloucester"]
tbl_rating = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
tbl_count = [6, 3, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7]
tbl_volume = [7.5, 5.7, 11.4, 11.4,
              22.0, 15.2, 21.0, 18.3,
              19.0, 9.0, 23.1, 16.0]


for namebreed, rating, numcows, volmilk in zip(tbl_breed, tbl_rating, tbl_count, tbl_volume):
    volmik = int(float(volmilk))
    
    dailyvol = (numcows * volmilk)
    print(namebreed, ":", dailyvol)


At the end of the first loop, totallist is ['Gloucester', 2, 7, 16.0].  You should have seen this for yourself, because you have print(totallist) in the loop.
Then your second loop iterates over each item in that list. total becomes 'Gloucester' on the first iteration, and therefore namebreed is first element of that string (the letter 'G'), rating is the second element of that string (the letter 'l'), and so on.
volmilk is the fourth element of that string, the letter 'u'.

This looks more like a comment than an answer. Do you have a specific change that the OP could use?

@quamrana If I could have made this a comment, keeping the line spacing and other formatting, I would have.

Your code intends to iterate over totallist in order to extract the breed, rating, count and volume.
You just need to make a list of lists in totallist by using zip() to extract elements from all of your original lists at once:
tbl_breed = ["Red Chittagong", "Sussex", "Dexter", "Abondance",
             "Sahiwal", "Vorderwald", "Ayrshire", "Jersey",
             "Randall", "Alderney", "Carora", "Gloucester"]
tbl_rating = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
tbl_count = [6, 3, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7]
tbl_volume = [7.5, 5.7, 11.4, 11.4,
              22.0, 15.2, 21.0, 18.3,
              19.0, 9.0, 23.1, 16.0]
tbl_dailyVolume = []
dailyvol = 0

totallist = [[breed, rating, count, volume] for (breed, rating, count, volume) in zip(tbl_breed, tbl_rating, tbl_count, tbl_volume)]


for total in totallist:
    namebreed = total[0]
    rating = total[1]
    numcows = total[2]
    volmilk = total[3]

    volmik = int(float(volmilk))
    
    dailyvol = (numcows * volmilk)
    print(namebreed, ":", dailyvol)

Output:
Red Chittagong : 45.0
Sussex : 17.1
Dexter : 91.2
Abondance : 79.8
Sahiwal : 132.0
Vorderwald : 60.8
Ayrshire : 63.0
Jersey : 128.1
Randall : 57.0
Alderney : 27.0
Carora : 92.4
Gloucester : 112.0


You "just" need to - I think it needs a bit more than that to explain your 1-liner :P Their original question stated that this was a GCSE student, so ~15/16 years old
